# Algorithm to convert the given whole number into the custom binary representation

Tags: algorithm, binary

**Problem Statement**

I have two different patterns to represent whole numbers using binary digits as follows:

First (the standard decimal to binary conversion):

```
0 -> 000
1 -> 001
2 -> 010
3 -> 011
4 -> 100
5 -> 101
6 -> 110
7 -> 111
```

Second:

```
0 -> 0000
1 -> 0001
2 -> 0010
3 -> 0100
4 -> 1000
5 -> 0011
6 -> 0101
7 -> 1001
8 -> 0110
9 -> 1010
10 -> 1100
11 -> 0111
12 -> 1011
13 -> 1101
14 -> 1110
15 -> 1111
```

Explaination: First, take flip one bit each, highest priority to the least significant bit. Then in second iteration, keep first bit flipped and then flip the rest bits in order as before. In the third iteration, the least significant bit is unset, and then second significant bit set and then pattern continued.

But now, let's say I want to combine the first and second pattern into one single pattern where some parts are defined by the first patten while the others are defined by the second pattern. For example:

(First pattern, most 3 significant digits)(Second pattern, least 3 significant digits)

```
0 -> 000000
1 -> 000001
2 -> 000010
3 -> 000100
4 -> 000011
5 -> 000101
6 -> 000110
7 -> 000111
8 -> 001000
9 -> 001001
10 -> 001010
11 -> 001100
12 -> 001011
13 -> 001101
14 -> 001110
15 -> 001111
16 -> 010000
17 -> 010001
...
010111
011000
...
```

**The goal:**

Input which tells which group of bits have which of these 2 patterns (no. of bits can be as long as we want and the pattern repetition can keep shifting between groups of bits in this set infinitely); a whole number.

Output which converts the whole number to the corresponding binary representation based on the input pattern. `E.g. 12 -> 001011`

**Where I am stuck:**

The binary conversion is straight forward. The second pattern, I'm not really sure how to make. Even if I can convert the whole number to the second pattern binary representation, how could I combine the both types to find the correct binary equivalent for my input number? Since there is a pattern here, I'm sure there must be an elegant mathematical representation for this!

**What is my use case?**

I'm writing a code for an application where I want to create a search pattern similar to this binary representation, based on a similar type of input.

Comment: The second pattern is identical to the first, except 3 and 4 are reversed. You can switch with two "if" blocks.

Comment: @LSerni but that's only when its 3 bits. When its 4 bits, it starts looking very different.

Comment: Then you should include the four bits pattern; please understand that we can only answer to what you write, not to something "looking very different" that we can't possibly know.

Comment: I updated to include the 4 bit pattern. I am finding difficulty in explaining it, I apologise. Basically, its like first, I want to only flip one bit in all possible bit positions. Then in second iteration, flip only 2 bits till all combinations are covered, but make sure I first keep the least significant bit set and then in order set the other bit, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have calculated first pattern and second pattern for a number.

Convert them back to "normal" decimal and then left shift firstNumber by 3 `firstPatterNo << 3` and then do OR of 2 numbers `firstPatterNo | secondPatterNo`.

```
firstPatterNo = 3 // 011  (normal decimal representations)
secondPatternNo = 4 // 100  (normal decimal representations)

combined = (firstPatterNo << 3) | secondPatternNo

// Convert combined to normal binary representation
```

BTW whats the logic behind second pattern ? I am not able to figure out.

Comment: I updated my question to maybe reflect this more clearly

Comment: As you said, you have figure out how to get first and second pattern representation. You are just struggling with combining of these 2 patters. Are your pattersn in string format ? Then you can simply append 1 after the other